# How to setup MySQL Rider - MacOS

Tags: mysql, database, docker, rider

Few weeks ago I started to learn C# (through course) and next step is database.
Sadly for me, everything is shown on Visual Studio, but VS doesn't support databases on MacOS. I am using Rider - was recommended to me by MacBook user - lecturer. Unfortunately he's not available for this part of course. I am having issue with Rider and MySQL. It doesn't work. Can somebody help me with the setup? Tried to google things out, but it didn't help me.

Sending some screenshots.
btw. if I use SQLlite it works perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help!
[image: thats when i try to save some scheme]

Tried to download Docker - don't know if I was supposed to, and some setups. But it didn't help.

edit. Well on one side I'm glad (that I'm not alone who doesn't know it) but sad, that noone can help me...

Comment: have you tried the recommendation on the webpage https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/macos-installation.html

Comment: I didn't try this. But the thing is, that I don't know to "connect" it to the Rider. Or to set it properly.

Comment: Downloaded the MySQL. Can you please help me how to setup Rider? What to put in Host, userName and password(that I set. Do I have  to put something in "database" and url too?